# Column is "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: php, sql, firebird

I have an INV_MASTER table which stores the list of items in the inventory each day, and an ITEM_MASTER table which has the list of items and its details (eg. department, sub-department, class, sub-class, etc.).

I am trying to write a query to fetch the list of items(INV_MASTER) in the inventory from the date range, arranged in ascending order according to the item's category(ITEM_MASTER). Here is my query its throwing exception.

```
SELECT
INV_MASTER.LOC_CODE,
INV_MASTER.INV_DATE,
INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE,
INV_MASTER.ITEM_DESC,
INV_MASTER.UNIT_DESC,
FIRST(INV_MASTER.BEG_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.SOLD_QTY),    
SUM(INV_MASTER.REC_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.RET_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.ADJ_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.COUNT_P),
SUM(INV_MASTER.COUNT_C),
SUM(INV_MASTER.TRANS_IN),
SUM(INV_MASTER.TRANS_OUT),
LAST(INV_MASTER.END_QTY),
ITEM_MASTER.*
FROM INV_MASTER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_MASTER ON INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE 
WHERE ITEM_MASTER.DEPARTMENT = '$department' AND ITEM_MASTER.SUB_DEPARTMENT = '$subdepartment' AND ITEM_MASTER.CLASS = '$class' AND ITEM_MASTER.SUB_CLASS = '$subclass' AND INV_MASTER.INV_DATE BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
GROUP BY INV_MASTER.LOC_CODE, INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE 
ORDER BY ITEM_MASTER.$type_desc, INV_MASTER.INV_DATE, ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE
```

Here's my code for printing:

```
while($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $inv_date = $row['INV_DATE'];
    $item_code = $row['ITEM_CODE'];
    $item_desc = $row['ITEM_DESC'];
    $unit_desc = $row['UNIT_DESC'];
    $sold_qty = $row['SUM(SOLD_QTY)'];
    $beg_qty = $row['FIRST(BEG_QTY)'];
    $rec_qty = $row['SUM(REC_QTY)'];
    $ret_qty = $row['SUM(RET_QTY)'];
    $adj_qty = $row['SUM(ADJ_QTY)'];
    $count_p_qty = $row['SUM(COUNT_P)'];
    $count_c_qty = $row['SUM(COUNT_C)'];
    $trans_in_qty = $row['SUM(TRANS_IN)'];  
    $trans_out_qty = $row['SUM(TRANS_OUT)'];
    $end_qty = $row['LAST(END_QTY)'];

    *printing part here*
}
```

Comment: This is tagged MySQL , but this is not MySQL . Please edit Accordingly

Comment: A side note: if you want to retrieve columns by name, then you need to alias those that use an aggregate function, so `$sold_qty = $row['SUM(SOLD_QTY)'];` is not going to work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, i'm not sure but i've tried using it before and it works

Answer (score 4):

The error messages says it: All columns in the `SELECT` clause must be either aggregate functions (e.g. `SUM`, `FIRST`) or in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You have

```
INV_MASTER.LOC_CODE, INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE
```

in the `GROUP BY` clause, but you SELECT

```
INV_MASTER.LOC_CODE,
INV_MASTER.INV_DATE,
INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE,
INV_MASTER.ITEM_DESC,
INV_MASTER.UNIT_DESC,
ITEM_MASTER.*
```

without any aggregate function. Either

- Remove the non-aggregated columns you don't need from the `SELECT` clause or
- Extend the `GROUP BY` clause by these columns

As far as I can tell from your PHP code, you only need the non-aggregated columns

```
INV_DATE, ITEM_CODE, ITEM_DESC, UNIT_DESC
```

in the `SELECT` part. So remove the rest and make sure that the `GROUP BY` contains all these four columns.

*Edit: Based on the SqlFiddle input*

The SQL Fiddle data is not really complete, and the request looks very different than in the first question (where you had far more items in the WHERE clause), but I managed to get a running statement.

```
SELECT
ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE,
ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_DESC,
ITEM_MASTER.UNIT_DESC,
ITEM_MASTER.CLASS,
MIN(INV_MASTER.BEG_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.SOLD_QTY),    
SUM(INV_MASTER.REC_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.RET_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.ADJ_QTY),
SUM(INV_MASTER.COUNT_P),
SUM(INV_MASTER.COUNT_C),
SUM(INV_MASTER.TRANS_IN),
SUM(INV_MASTER.TRANS_OUT),
MAX(INV_MASTER.END_QTY)
FROM INV_MASTER
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_MASTER ON INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE 
WHERE INV_MASTER.INV_DATE BETWEEN '2015-10-27' AND '2015-10-31'
GROUP BY ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_DESC, ITEM_MASTER.UNIT_DESC, ITEM_MASTER.CLASS
ORDER BY ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, INV_MASTER.INV_DATE, ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE
```

I hope this is more or less what you want, I think it'll be easy to adapt anyway. As your inserted data in SQLFiddle did not include all fields, I couldn't really get the same results as you wish.

Keep in mind, MySQL does *not* know the functions `FIRST` and `LAST`, therefore I have changed them to MIN and MAX, not sure, if that's ok, though.

Comment: i've tried removing these columns (`INV_MASTER.ITEM_DESC,
INV_MASTER.UNIT_DESC`) and replacing `ITEM_MASTER.*` to `ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE` in the `SELECT` clause, the error message now says "Invalid expression in the `ORDER BY` clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause)". help please?

Comment: You also have to remove INV_MASTER.INV_DATE from SELECT clause or add this column to GROUP BY clause.

Comment: yep, already did @MaximVotyakov, but not sure though if `ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE` is necessary, here's my updated `GROUP BY` clause `GROUP BY INV_MASTER.LOC_CODE, INV_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, INV_MASTER.INV_DATE`

Comment: @KarenD I lost track on how your SQL looks now, can you post the updated version, please?

Comment: @marco sure, wait, I'll use sqlfiddle for you.

Comment: @marco I have the tables here with sample values [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b823f], and with those sample values, i want the result to look something like this

Comment: @marco please see answer below. i want the result to look exactly like that, help please? :3

Answer (score 0):

from the tables and sample data here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b823f the output should look something like this when i query dates from `'2015-10-27'` to `'2015-10-31'`. it should also be group according to its item's department (eg. metal, painting..)

```
ITEM_CODE      | ITEM_DESC                              | UNIT_DESC | CLASS | BEG  | + | - | - | - | + | + | + | + | - | - | END
METAL  
000000000MS016 | MS RHS 50 X 150 X 3MM X 6M             | LENGTH    | NONE  | 12.5 |20 |25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |30 | 0 | 5 | 32.5
PAINTING
000000000PN044 | DURAPATCH BODYFILLER W/ CREAM HARDENER | GALLON/S  | NONE  | 0    |70 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |   65
NONE 
000000000VI064 | TURQOUISE STICKER 3630-236             | SQR FT    | NONE  | 440  | 5 | 0 |10 | 0 |10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 0 |  437
ART
000000000VI029 | 3M PLUM PURPLE 3630-128                | SQR FT    | NONE  | 274  |35 |10 | 0 |25 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 4 |  273
```